# Restore in-app purchases for sandbox user seems to validate for a new user even though they never purchased the app

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, sandbox, restore

I'm following a tutorial found here for in-app purchases: https://hackernoon.com/swift-how-to-add-in-app-purchases-in-your-ios-app-c1dc2fc82319

I've tested buying a non-consumable in-app purchase with a sandbox user. Then I created a new sandbox user and pressed my "Restore Purchase" button logged in with the new username and password, and to my surprise paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished is called and sets the purchaseStatusBlock to ".restored" without ever buying the app in the first place.

So I'm wondering how restoring the in-app purchases validates that the user first bought the app. This doesn't seem to do so.

Code below for the IAPHandler. Note that "restored" is never printed to the console for the paymentQueue function where it goes through transactionStates:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

enum IAPHandlerAlertType{
    case disabled
    case restored
    case purchased

    func message() -> String{
        switch self {
        case .disabled:  return "Purchases are disabled in your device!"
        case .restored:  return "You've successfully restored your purchase!"
        case .purchased: return "You've successfully bought this purchase!"
        }
    }
}


class IAPHandler: NSObject {
    static let shared = IAPHandler()

    //let CONSUMABLE_PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID = "testpurchase"
    let NON_CONSUMABLE_PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID = "HCUnlocked"

    fileprivate var productID = ""
    fileprivate var productsRequest = SKProductsRequest()
    fileprivate var iapProducts = [SKProduct]()

    var purchaseStatusBlock: ((IAPHandlerAlertType) -> Void)?

    // MARK: - MAKE PURCHASE OF A PRODUCT
    func canMakePurchases() -> Bool {  return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()  }

    func purchaseMyProduct(index: Int){
        if iapProducts.count == 0 { return }

        if self.canMakePurchases() {
            let product = iapProducts[index]
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

            print("PRODUCT TO PURCHASE: \(product.productIdentifier)")
            productID = product.productIdentifier
        } else {
            purchaseStatusBlock?(.disabled)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - RESTORE PURCHASE
    func restorePurchase(){
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }


    // MARK: - FETCH AVAILABLE IAP PRODUCTS
    func fetchAvailableProducts(){

        // Put here your IAP Products ID's separated by commas
        // i.e. CONSUMABLE_PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID, NON_CONSUMABLE_PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID
        // as the objects list in NSSet
        let productIdentifiers = NSSet(objects: NON_CONSUMABLE_PURCHASE_PRODUCT_ID
        )

        productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
    }
}

extension IAPHandler: SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver{
    // MARK: - REQUEST IAP PRODUCTS
    func productsRequest (_ request:SKProductsRequest, didReceive response:SKProductsResponse) {

        if (response.products.count > 0) {
            iapProducts = response.products
            for product in iapProducts{
                let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
                numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
                numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
                numberFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
                let price1Str = numberFormatter.string(from: product.price)
                print(product.localizedDescription + "\nfor just \(price1Str!)")
            }
        }
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished")
        purchaseStatusBlock?(.restored)
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

    // MARK:- IAP PAYMENT QUEUE
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
                switch trans.transactionState {
                case .purchased:
                    print("purchased")
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    purchaseStatusBlock?(.purchased)
                    break

                case .failed:
                    print("failed")
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                case .restored:
                    print("restored")
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break

                default: break
                }}}
    }
}
```

I have an action in my view that calls restorePurchase:

```
@IBAction func restorePurchaseAction(_ sender: Any) {
    IAPHandler.shared.restorePurchase()

}
```

In viewWillAppear(), I have the purchaseStatusBlock to see if the type was set to a ".restored" state, and changes the UI to allow them to use the purchased features again:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    IAPHandler.shared.purchaseStatusBlock = {[weak self] (type) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else{ return }
        if type == .purchased {
            strongSelf.applyPurchaseSettingsWithUIFX()
        }
        else if type == .restored {
            strongSelf.applyPurchaseSettingsWithUIFX()
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you making a new sandbox user each time you want to test? If not, that's the problem. It's a pain in the butt but it's what you have to do.

Comment: Yes I created a new sandbox user and tested the restore without purchasing first (expecting it to fail), but it didn't! And that's my problem.

Comment: Well, that's not my experience. My experience is just the opposite: if the sandbox user tries to restore without having purchased, `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` is not called, and then the difficulty for me is discovering that anything happened at all! That's the problem that I discuss here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276769/calling-skpaymentqueue-restorecompletedtransactions-no-response

Comment: That tutorial doesn't show how to handle restoration properly. The payment transaction observer should call the payment block with a state of `.purchased` in the restoration case as well.  The `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` indicates that the restore process is complete. It doesn't indicate whether or not there was anything to restore. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506101-paymentqueuerestorecompletedtran  If no purchase is available to restore then this is the only method that will be called

Comment: @Paulw11 And that's also what my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276769/calling-skpaymentqueue-restorecompletedtransactions-no-response explains.

Comment: So my problem might be that I should set my applications state to purchased if it gets through paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:) with a transactionState of .restored. I'm doing it through the purchaseStatusBlock, which I thought was the whole point of it anyway.

Comment: Yes, your code assumes that a call to `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` indicates that there was a transaction to restore, but this isn't the case. It just means that anything that was there to be restored has been. A user may have several prior purchases to restore, which is why they are delivered through the payment queue observer.

Comment: I think I figured it out. (With your help of course!) In the ".restored" case inside paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:) is where purchaseStatusBlock?(.restored) should be called. I tested it by first hitting Restore, seeing that paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished was called, but not the restored case. It was only when I bought it, simulated a reinstall and hit Restore is when the ".restored" case was triggered, updating my app to a purchased state.