# How to properly restore purchases using IAP in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to display an alert to the user when purchases are restored. But when i debug and print out the number of restored purchases i get 0 transactions were restored. I don't understand why it would bring back 0. I thought i only needed to call to `restoreCompletedTransactions()` method. I post a notification to notify me if restoration has completed and i doesn't even reach this point. I'm using
`paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ pQueue: SKPaymentQueue)` to notify me when restoration is done. How can i properly restore the purchases.

```
let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()

func restorePurchases() {
    if !self.canMakePurchases {
            return
     }
     self.paymentQueue.add(self)
     self.paymentQueue.restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
     print("Restore failed")
}

func paymentQueue(_ pQueue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions pTransactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
     for scanTransaction in pTransactions {
         switch scanTransaction.transactionState {
          case .purchasing:
             break
          case .purchased:
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .AppDelegateUserHasPurchasedProductNotification, object: self)
            pQueue.finishTransaction(scanTransaction)
          default:
            pQueue.finishTransaction(scanTransaction)
        }
    }
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ pQueue: SKPaymentQueue) {
     print("Received restored transactions: \(pQueue.transactions.count)")
     for scanTansaction in pQueue.transactions {
        switch scanTansaction.transactionState {
         case .restored:
           NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .AppDelegateUserHasRestoredPurchasesNotification, object: self)
           pQueue.finishTransaction(scanTansaction)
          default:
             break
            }
      }
}
```

The Logs

```
Received restored transactions: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of

```
func paymentQueue(_ pQueue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions pTransactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
```

is wrong. You have left out the transaction state for when a purchase is restored! You have `case .purchased` but you forgot `case .restored`. Put it in. That is where you are notified and can respond.

Comment: i have added it and still don't get notified

Comment: I do not know what you have now. What know is that the code in your question is totally wrong. You cannot use paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished that way.

Comment: i have added the `.purchased` case but still doesnt work.  Still don't get notified and when debugging it doesn't even come to this point when i try restoring.

Comment: Might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276769/calling-skpaymentqueue-restorecompletedtransactions-no-response